# How to toggle a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, toggle

I have a question. How would I toggle a jQuery plugin with a button. So for example. Let's say I made a plugin that turns all `<div>` elements red. How would I set up a button so when I click it, it turns all the `<div>` elements red, and when I click it again it reverses the effects? If you need anymore info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @4castle That was just an example. My actual plugin does something else.

Comment: Ok, so can you please give a better example? (my comment was to use `.toggleClass()`)

Comment: @4castle OK lets say its a parallax plugin. So when I press a button it turns it on, and when I press it again, it turns it off.

Comment: Without calling some kind of `turn off` function on the plugin, there wouldn't be a way to undo the effects of loading the plugin, because only the plugin knows how it was done in the first place. The answer would be plugin-specific. Is there a specific plugin you would like to ask about?

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing a CSS class to the  elements is one way to do it:

CSS

```
.red{
background-color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
     <button id="toggleButton">Click Me!</button>
```

JS & JQUERY

```
        var toggle=0;  //Start with the toggle state as off

        function toggleRed(){

          if (toggle===0){
          $('div').addClass("red"); //add the class 'red' to all divs
          toggle=1;  //Save the toggle state as on until the next click

          }else{

          $('div').removeClass("red"); //remove the class 'red' from all divs
          toggle=0; //Save the toggle state as off until the next click

          }
        }

        $("#toggleButton").click(function{toggleRed()});//attach event handler to button
```

Or a shorter way to do the JS/JQUERY:

```
    $("#toggleButton").click(function{
     $( "div" ).toggleClass( "red" );
    })
```

Comment: Its not a class. That div thing was just an example. I need to know how to toggle a plugin. Not a class.